# what is the most pythoic way of indexing a file?

Tags: python, indexing

(Caveat: I am a newbie to the python language)

What would be the most pythonic way of indexing a file, where my script would return the word, followed by all the lines on which the word occured?

Here is an example text I would use in my script.

It was the best of times,
it was the worst of times,
it was the age of wisdom,
it was the age of foolishness,
it was the epoch of belief,
it was the epoch of incredulity,
it was the season of Light,
it was the season of Darkness,
it was the spring of hope,
it was the winter of despair,
we had everything before us,
we had nothing before us,
we were all going direct to Heaven,
we were all going direct the other way--
in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of
its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for
evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only.

Comment: Errata: _it was the age of foolishness_ should read _this is the age of foolishness_.

Comment: @devnull Really? I can't find a source for that (and it doesn't fit the pattern).

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Asking for someone to do your homework for you by pretending you just want to be "more pythonic" (which doesn't even mean anything) is... well, ok, probably someone will just do your homework for you, but they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collections module is your friend for this question. I would use a defaultdict, use the words in the text as the keys and the values would be the line numbers where the word has occurred.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for index, line in enumerate(txt.splitlines()):
    for word in line:
        word_strip = word.strip(',.!?')
        d[word_strip].append(index)
```

I have assumed that the text is contained in a variable txt, also that you want to want to get rid of the various punctuation characters.